# Why are F3 database queries on views not working with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, fat-free-framework

I'm setting up an API using the fatfree framework and want to use sqlite in development. I followed the docs (https://fatfreeframework.com/3.7/databases). At the bottom of that page, I learned about using a view containing joins instead of joining while querying. I thought that a very good idea. However, it seems to be working in mysql but not in sqlite.

```php
$prefs = new Mapper($this->db, 'userpreferences');
$prefs->load(array('login_id=?', $userLoginId));
```

In mysql this works. In sqlite this yields the following error:

```sh
PDO: near "FROM": syntax error
```

However, if use the view in an exec() everything works in mysql and sqlite.

```php
$prefs = $this->db->exec('SELECT * FROM userpreferences WHERE login_id=?', $userLoginId);
```

Is this a (known) bug or am I missing something?
(php: 7.4, F3: 3.7.3, sqlite3: 3.32.2, mysql: 8.0.25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon same issue and you can get around it by editing lib/db/sql.php file on line 342: https://github.com/jlazic/fatfree/commit/ad5a86819a60b51b124660fddd7ad5eec61ab48f

Issue seems to be that sqlite uses type=view for views, while f3 only queries for metadata where type=table.

Comment: Please report this issue on GitHub.

Comment: @svakak - will you do a merge request on GitHub?
I can't find any tests in that repo. Maybe they have some internal testing proc.